# fullCalendar - Event title and detail

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, rendering

I'm using the pretty fullCalendar jQuery plugin.

I'd like to be able to have a title AND a detail on each event as in the screenshot below:

[image]

Here the details are the participants for each session.
(overflow hidden on the detail)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[See This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433826/305189) (Eureka's Answer)

```
eventRender: function(event, element)
{ 
    element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<br/>" + event.description); 
}
```

Comment: Thx, I didn't find this thread before. This is a good solution.

Comment: '.fc-event-title' is no longer used, use '.fc-title' as your selector

Comment: Is this the proper way to do this ? what if class name changes on newer versions ?

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed eventRender no longer exists in v5.

Comment: @SvenCazier what's the alternative solution to eventRender for v5?

Comment: use the `eventDidMount` callback and access the `extendedProps` data, as per answer below

Answer (score 6):

Based on **fullcalendar** documentation

### V5

If you want to set the title use `eventDidMount` instead of `eventRender`

```
eventDidMount:function(info){
   info.el.title="---- YOUR TEXT----"
}
```

Comment: Note that doesn't change the displayed text (at least in "list" views), I use `mountArg.el.children[2].innerHTML = "Custom title with <b>HTML Tag</b>"` to di this. 
Just use the correct children which may be different from my example based on view type.

Comment: `info.el.title` not work in v6, use `info.event.setProp("title", "");` instead

Comment: You are correct with the `eventDidMount` callback, although the way to access the data is via the `extendedProps` key as per example below.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (V6) a solution is to use the `eventDidMount` callback and access the `extendedProps` data:

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {
  var eventElement = info.el;
  let descriptionElement = document.createElement('div');
  descriptionElement.innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.description;
  eventElement.appendChild(descriptionElement);
}
```

Style your element to display as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody having this issue in Angular 8:

```
eventRender: function(event, element)
{ 
    (element as Element).querySelector('span.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.description); 
}
```