# Customizing events in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, event-handling, fullcalendar

Currently, the event component looks as follows:

[image: single event component]

I want to customize it, and the final result should look as follows:

[image: customized event component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post gave me a tip to solve my issue - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408723/display-more-text-in-fullcalendar`

Event object looks this way:

```
  title: ` ${firstname} ${lastname} `,
      start: new Date("2022-10-10 12:00"),
      end: new Date("2022-10-10 13:00"),
      id: "1",
      extendedProps: {
        services: [
          { title: 'text1', price: '80$' },
          { title: 'text2', price: '90$' },
          { title: 'text3', price: '100$' },
        ]
      }
    },
```

In fullcalendar v5 version in `eventDidMount` hook I put function
(`<FullCalendar eventDidMount={returnContent} />`)
that looks the following way:

```
function returnContent(e) {
  const time = e.timeText
  const title = e.event['_def'].title
  const services = e.event['_def'].extendedProps.services

  if(services) {
    e.el.innerHTML = `
      ${time}
      ${title}
      ${services.map(({title, price}) => (
        `<div class={customClasses}>
          <span>${title}</span>
          <span>${price}</span>
        </div>`
      )).join('')}
    `
  }
}
```

Comment: this seems like a hack - I don't think the `_def` property being undocumented is a coincidence. This could easily break in any future revisions. It would be better to keep your additional event data in a separate array and cross reference the two arrays by a shared key.